# How to best create an animation of an opening paper fan?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature, workflow

I an trying to create a 10 second animation of an opening paper fan which would look similar to that depicted in the image (C4D, apologies, couldn't find any blender images related to this exact animation.)

Would I use one mesh, cut it with the knife and rig it up with an armature or...?

Any help would be great
[image: example paper fan object]

Comment: The answers to this paper folding [question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57976/2217) may help you.

Comment: I am totally new to blender this link is totally over my head. It looks really helpful but I am a total beginner. Thanks for posting it though :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one to try out. The base is a Plane with one vertical cut [<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>] and the lower vertices merged [<kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>]. It is shaped to approximate one fold of the fan. Hooks are added to the outer vertices by selecting them in Edit mode and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>. Once back in Object mode the hooks can be (shift) selected and moved down on the Z-Axis or scaled towards each other to create the fold.

[image: Add Hooks]

You can later animate the Location by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>. The single fold can be duplicated with an array modifier using a new empty as the centre.

[image: Empty array rotation]

The centre empty rotation can also be animated with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to match the timing of the Hook movement. Of course it is cheating and if you look too closely they might not match perfectly..

[image]

Comment: Cool solution man! I thought to use bones, but this one is much faster and smarter I guess.

Comment: Wow this looks fantastic! Thanks a mill :)