# Origami animation in blender 2,8

Tags: animation

Could someone guide me to create a simple folding animation of an Origami Plane?
version 2.8 or 2.81 if possible.

I will really appreciate.

Comment: [How to simulate Miura-fold](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57976/2217) It is from 2.7x but should still point you in the right direction.

Comment: I just commented on [a post similar to yours](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170736/) from around the same era. While I don't believe I can illustrate a process specifically enough to give an answer, I have at least outlined what the main challenges are. It could serve as a starting point for someone looking into this.