# how to animate complex origami folds in 2.8?

Tags: animation, modifiers, armature, bones, shape-keys

I've reviewed the questions regarding origami animations in this StackExchange and I've not quite found what I'm looking for.

I have tried using shape keys to animate complex folds in a plane, such as inside-reverse folds, sinks, etc. To start off with something relatively simple in my project, I am trying to create the Skeleton Hand origami model by Jeremy Shafer; this has very few complex folds but I'm still having trouble using multiple shape keys to deform my plane.

I'm looking into how to use armatures and hooks, but I'm a complete beginner when it comes to animation and I could use some guidance if anybody has any ideas. Thanks!

Comment: Origami is notoriously difficult to animate using 3D software's conventional methods. Modeling a finished piece is not so tricky, but *animating* the folding process can be very complex. Some of the challenges include: ① Preserving **planar surface area** without distortion, so as to reflect physical material properties (we can't allow the paper to stretch like rubber, even a little). ② Dealing with the **topology** of the mesh changing *as the creation is being made*. ③ Needing **multiple rigs** for each folding step, that change with topology (one curve/tuck can require a new IK bone chain).

Comment: ④ With a 3D mesh we can't rely on accurate **collision detection** to give our shapes their structure. Faces can easily end up intersecting through one another after layered folding. For these reasons, I believe specialized software or an advanced addon will be needed before it can be done reliably/efficiently/convincingly. If I were tasked with animating a scene in which a character folds origami, I would start with mocap of a person folding the design, then make a new retopo'd mesh every few folds, and swap it in. Finally use video cuts from different angles where continuity is hard to show.